# How to run manage.py runserver in django

Tags: django

I have made a Django app, am running it in Python with `manage.py`, and accessing it with a `URL` using `ip:port`.

```
URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

Now I want to change `ip:port` to a static url: `http:/testapp.com/admin`.
I tried changing it in `/etc/host` but it only changed the `IP` as
`127.0.0.1` testapp

Can I change the `IP:PORT` to a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope... Only solution is to run in `port` `80` so 0.0.0.0:80 becomes testapp.com or whatever

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to run

```
./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80
```

as superuser and then update your `/etc/hosts` file to make `testapp.com` point to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do it is to run in Port **80**

```
./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80
```